# How to read an image file as a Base 64 string, over http, without curl?

Tags: php

I am using `PHP` for my work. Now, I want to get your help about my problem in `PHP`.

Someone has a server which isn't allowed `allow_url_fopen`, and there is a image on this web site (http://www.url.com/uploads/image.jpg).

Can you show me the way to read this image file in `Base 64`, over `http`, without `curl`?

---

I know how to use `base64_encode();`.

Comment: What are the steps you already tried to achieve your goal?

Comment: @Seb, I am sorry, **I don't want to use `curl`**. Please stop down-vote my question! Do you read my question carefully?

Comment: @Seb, I have tried these steps... If I use `file_get_contents();`, I will recive a empty string. Because, `allow_url_fopen` is **off**.